# Using mathematica to visualise solution of vectors and planes

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra

Im struggling with a question I'm my math book and I wanted to use mathematica to visualise it for me, the problem is that I don't even get something remotely similar to what I was expecting. How here is the question and this is how I have visualised it. Could someone please show me the correct way also point out if it is the mathematics that is incorrect and why.

I have already looked at previous examples but some how I get stuck with this one. I know that there are several answers on the web but Im not able to use it to solve this.

So question, visualise the intersection of the planes.

```
eq1 = x + y == 2;
eq2 = y - z == 3;

{b, a} = CoefficientArrays[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y, z}];
point = LinearSolve[a, -b] // N;(*Solves for point on intersection*)
Cross @@ Reverse[a // Normal];(*Finds the direction vector of the plane*)
line = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{point, 10 {1, -1, -1}}]}](*Draws the vector*)
```

Now what I was expecting was a red dot, somewhere along the line of intersection between the planes and a red vector being the line intersection for part of the planes intersection. (In particular line of length 10)

```
Show[Plot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> Blue], 
Plot3D[y - z == 3, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green], 
Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[point]}], line, 
PlotLabel -> "Point where surfaces meet", BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myPlanes = Graphics3D[
  {{Opacity[0.5], Yellow, 
    Polygon[{{2, 0, -3}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, -3}, {2, 
       0, -3}}]},
   {Opacity[0.5], Blue, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0, -3}, {0, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 0, -3}, {0, 
       0, -3}}]}},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
  ]

myIntersection = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 2 - x, -x - 1}, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[myPlanes, myIntersection]
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to solve the problem in my code as well?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I wouldn't address the problem by your fundamental method.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: @ALEXANDER For one thing, your constraint $x + y = 2$ does not define a function $z$, and hence cannot be plotted using `Plot3D`.

Comment: Okey, not sure if I get that, since this is a plane and the fact that z is not restricted is what makes it a plane.

Comment: @ALEXANDER  Think about it.  Try to write a function $z = f(x,y)$ that describes the $x + y = 2$ constraint.  You simply cannot do it.  And `Plot3D` demands you cast your surface as `Plot3D[z, {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}]`.  Go ahead... just try to do that!

Comment: I am understanding everything of the plotting now, apart from the myIntersection. Cause converting the scalar parametric plot to standard form gives me a different values from yours (being x, 2 - x, -x - 1)

Answer (score 4):

An embellished variant of  @kajames' answer using `ContourPlot3D`:

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[{x + y == 2, y - z == 3}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]]},
   Mesh -> False, 
   BoundaryStyle-> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Cyan, Tube@@#&]}];
g3d = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere@point, Arrow[Tube@{point, 10 {1, -1, -1}}]}];

Legended[Show[cp, g3d],
 SwatchLegend[{Blue, Green}, Style[ToString@#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {x+y == 2, y-z == 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: It seems that `Plot3D` silently transforms the first argument to `x + y - 2` when passed `x + y ==2` as the first argument:

```
Plot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] == 
   Plot3D[x + y - 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
(* True *)
```

To visualize the two planes generated by `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot3D`:

```
plt1 = Plot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
         PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Green]];
cp1 = ContourPlot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
         Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red]];
legend = SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@
      {"Plot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]",
      "ContourPlot3D[x + y \[Equal] 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]"}];

Legended[Show[plt1, cp1, BoxRatios -> 1], legend]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use ContourPlot3D to draw planes:

```
ContourPlot3D[x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10},
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> False]
```

Also, the second point for your Arrow should add to point.

(As an aside, I'm sorry if this would be better as a comment to the question; I don't have the rep)